# LinkedIn will limit its open APIs

Tags: api, limit, linkedin-api

[In this blogpost](https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/posts/2015/developer-program-changes) linkedin has announced new limits to the APIs to just four uses:

- Allowing members to represent their professional identity via their LinkedIn profile using our Profile API.
- Enabling members to post certifications directly to their LinkedIn profile with our Add to Profile tools.
- Enabling members to share professional content to their LinkedIn network from across the Web leveraging our Share API.
- Enabling companies to share professional content to LinkedIn with our Company API.

I think this information is kind of confusing, what is the limits here?

Will it be possible to fetch profile data without being a parnter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting on May 12, 2015, LinkedIn will be limiting the open APIs to only support the 4 uses mentioned in the question. All other APIs will require developers to become a member of one of our partnership programs.

In other words open access to other APIs won't be available since May 12.

**Will it be possible to fetch profile data without being a parnter?**

As I understand it this is covered by first use: allowing members to represent their professional identity via their LinkedIn profile using our Profile API.

Comment: Thanks. It is so typical that they write it in a way that can be understood in 100 ways

Answer (score 0):

Yes, "open" API users will still be able to access profile data after May 12.